# Объединить [списки]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba), [списки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8) и [list](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list).

Comment: В них кстати каша из разных понятий. Часть про связные списки, часть про List в .NET (который на самом деле является массивом переменной длины), немного про html.

Comment: Голосую вообще за уничтожение `list`, так как в питоне это тоже массив, лишь путаницы добавляет

Comment: @andreymal уничтожение меток не продуктивно, их создадут снова.

Comment: @alexolut тогда есть предложение запрещать создавать определённые метки)

Comment: @andreymal мы не в ГосДуме, чтоб на каждый чих всё запрещать ;)

Comment: @alexolut а мы их снова удалим! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Голосуем:

#### Синонимизировать метки

Дополнительная информация:

- метка [list](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list): 413 вопросов (на момент просмотра) + есть описание;
- метка [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba): 199 вопросов (на момент просмотра), описания нет;
- метка [списки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8): 127 вопросов (на момент просмотра), описания нет;

Comment: Тогда предлагаю, чтобы основная метка была [tag:списки]

Comment: Метки не синонимизированы до сих пор?

Answer (score 1):

### Синонимизировать метки

Списки есть почти в любом языке программирования, но это не значит, что метка сама по себе является плохой из-за этого. У нас есть [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b) и [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b), которые тоже везде есть везде, но никто почему-то не стремится удалить (по крайней мере, не видел).

То что есть списки в HTML, означает, что надо будет выделить отдельную метку, что-то вроде [html-lists](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-lists) (как на enSO) или [html-списки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8), как это было сделать с меткой [select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) из которой выделили [html-select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select).

Answer (score 1):

Метка [list](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) вполне может означать одноимённую коллекцию в соответствующем языке программирования. С её синонимизацией стоит быть осторожным, потому что в некоторых случаях она должна превратиться в [связный-список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba), а не просто в [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba).

Т. е. сначала надо разгрести вопросы по этой метке и только потом синонимизировать. Ну или вообще её не синонимизировать и оставить для названия конкретных классов. Но мне всё-таки вариант с синонимизацией большеи нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Голосуем:

#### Удалить данные метки

Возможен вариант с редактированием вопросов и удалением данных меток из них.